# What is the plan to upgrade time_t for linux 32

Tags: linux, 32-bit

Linux currently has time_t as 32 bits on Linux 32 bit.  This will run out in less than 25 years (mortgage times) and Linux is being used embedded in devices with long > 10 year lifetimes (cars).  Is there an upgrade plan for this platform?

Comment: There's no bullet-proof solution. The plan is to use 64-bit values (which recent desktop Linux distributions already do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "set" time or time frame for which all Linux kernels will be using 64-bit time_t. In fact right now the general consensus is that it will not be changed anytime soon. No one is really that worried about it yet; just like Y2K it will cause problems in code that already relies on time_t.

There are a few Operating Systems that are using the workaround which is to use a wrapper that makes time_t both a 32-bit and a 64-bit integer.

While others have just forcibly upgraded time_t to use 64-bit integers.

For more information please refer to this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 2):

There were some good articles about it (specifically syscalls) on LWN. Have a look at [System call conversion for year 2038](https://lwn.net/Articles/643234/)